# Python: Transform my X_train distribution for machine learning

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, transform

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
X_Train = Wind_direction from 0 to 360 degree => Xaxis
Y_Train = Energy_Production => Yaxis
```

How can I transform my X_variable in order to obtain better results on my machine learning problem?

Optimal direction seems to be around 140 and 340 degrees

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some models depends heavily on the input data distribution, like neural networks or other gradient based techniques.
Some models do not really care about the distribution, like decison trees, random forests etc.

I would suggest to try out different normalization techniques, like the [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) (z-score) or a [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html?highlight=minmax#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) for a given range (like rescaling on [0.0, 1.0]).

In the end there is no universal answer which normalization techniques performans best, since it is dependend on the problem and the machine learning algorithm itself.